# Insert multiple rows with different ID

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a system in which there are dynamic rows and dynamic fields for each row. I am having a problem in inserting the dynamic row in to database through one ADD button.

when i am clicking that add button it save the data but the data is saving under one ID. it is not getting the name also. it is saving the first name for all. i am getting those names from database. so please help me to solve this problem. i am having the problem in adding that row with different ID.

**code for my form**

```
<form name="form1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select</td>
    <td width="103">Date</td>
    <td width="94">Backup_Name</td>
    <td width="94">No Of Tapes</td>
    <td width="53">Tape Code</td>    
    <td width="71">Operator Approval</td>
    <td width="144">Operator Remark</td>
    <td width="144">Submit</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
   if ($que->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($que)) {
   ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $Date;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Backup_Name'];  ?></td>
    <td class="No_Of_Backup[]" value="" /><a href="#" class="addNewTape">Add</a></td>
    <td class="Tape_Code"></td>
    <td class="Operator_Verify_Status"></td>
    <td class="Operator_Remark"></td>

</tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
<td><input type= "submit" value="add" name="add" onclick="submitdetails();"/></td>
</form>
```

my php code

```
<?php
include_once 'dpconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;
$que=mysqli_query($MySQLiconn ,"select Backup_Name from admin_backup_list ");
$ftch=mysqli_fetch_array($que);
$Backup_Name=$ftch['Backup_Name'];


if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

$query1 = "insert into backup_list (Backup_Name) values ('". $Backup_Name ."')";
mysqli_query($MySQLiconn, $query1);


$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($MySQLiconn);
$Date=date('y/m/d');
    foreach($_POST['Tape_Code'] as $key => $value){

        $Tape_Code = $_POST['Tape_Code'][$key];
        $Operator_Verify_Status = $_POST['Operator_Verify_Status'][$key];
        $Operator_Remark = $_POST['Operator_Remark'][$key];

        $query2= "insert into tapes (Backup_List_ID, Tape_Code,Operator_Verify_Status, Operator_Remark, Operator_Date) values ('". $last_id ."','". $Tape_Code ."','" .$Operator_Verify_Status ."','". $Operator_Remark ."','". $Date ."');";
        mysqli_query($MySQLiconn, $query2);
    }
}
?>
```

dynamic text field

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.addNewTape').on( "click", function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings(".Tape_Code").append('<input type="text" name="Tape_Code[]" value="'+ i +'"/><br>');
        $(this).parent().siblings(".Operator_Verify_Status").append('<SELECT name="Operator_Verify_Status[]"><OPTION value="verify">Verify</OPTION><OPTION value="NotVerify">Not Verify</OPTION><OPTION value="Failed">Failed</OPTION></SELECT><br>');
        $(this).parent().siblings(".Operator_Remark").append('<input type="text" name="Operator_Remark[]" value=""/><br>');
        i++;
    });

});


|backup list

id       name
-----------------

0        qwer
1        33344
2


tapes

id    code    approval
-----------------------
0      5959    yes
1      565     yes----->dynamic field
1      5656    yes----->dynamic field
2      8888    yes
```

i couldn't get these 1 , 1 in the database. now i am getting 0 for all

Comment: If Possible please share table structure and please check id(Primary key should be autoincrement)

Comment: primarykey is autoincrement. but couldn't get the values from 2nd 3rd rows. it only get the 1st row name

Comment: Please share table structure after I'll be able check query ....

Comment: One more thing I didn't seen any input fields so how you post your data?

Comment: those are dynamic field so i have done with js

Comment: Its bit challenging to understand your problem as you still not post tables structure also confuse about row name. you are select data from admin_backup_list table and after submit form you inserting it one another table backup_list. 
Please send Graphical result of tables which you want then we will be able to help you....

Comment: Sorry not able to help you Please share your requirment in some GUI format and as table structure what data you want in it....

Comment: now can you able to help me

Comment: I am sorry but I am not able understand your requirement...Please text me below facebook id or if you use skype please call me
FB :- https://www.facebook.com/VishaalChaturvedi
Skype:- vishal.chatuvedi_sipl

Answer (score 0):

**you fetched the data without while loop so fetch the data in while loop like this:**

```
    while ($ftch=mysqli_fetch_array($que)) {
        if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

            $query1 = "insert into backup_list (Backup_Name) values ('". $Backup_Name ."')";
            mysqli_query($MySQLiconn, $query1);


            $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($MySQLiconn);
            $Date=date('y/m/d');

            foreach($_POST['Tape_Code'] as $key => $value){

                $Tape_Code = $_POST['Tape_Code'][$key];
                $Operator_Verify_Status = $_POST['Operator_Verify_Status'][$key];
                $Operator_Remark = $_POST['Operator_Remark'][$key];

                $query2= "insert into tapes (Backup_List_ID,  Tape_Code,Operator_Verify_Status, Operator_Remark, Operator_Date) values ('". $last_id ."','". $Tape_Code ."','" .$Operator_Verify_Status ."','". $Operator_Remark ."','". $Date ."');";
                mysqli_query($MySQLiconn, $query2);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: same it get the first row name for all.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ID column of your database on AUTO INCREMENT so that it automatically generates ID's for new records. Most databases support auto increment; since you're using MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: i have that ID that's called backuplistID... i couldn't get that id into another table where have to insert other data (query2). on query 2 data base i am getting only the first row id of query1 database